# Is it possible to burn an NFT (ERC20 or ERC721) from other provider/creator?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, nft

I want to create a wallet/gallery for NFTs and I was wondering if it could be possible for the user to send NFTs made in other providers/minters to burn in my platform. The thing is that I want to give a 'grace period' where the NFT is not burned yet. Is possible to do something like this? The ideal way is that the user allows the permission to burn but is not done until the proper time arrives.

Thanks a lot for any hint*

Answer (score 2):

Practically, yes. The [ERC-721 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) supports a `transfer` function. You can use that to allow people to send you tokens.

Then you can use `transfer` again to send them to the one address. This is a well-known address that is unable to recover any assets sent to it. (The zero address is better known with the same feature, but the standard specifically disallows sending there.) This is an effective burn.

But the standard specifically does not standardize burning. Your new contract could use the above approach in general along with more specific proprietary burning approaches as needed on a per-asset-type basis.

Comment: Thanks! In this case I'm thinking that the user brings her own minted NFTs.. so can I do like a 'wrap' that takes her minted NFT, keeps the original ownership but with her permission to burn said NFT in a later timedate?

Comment: Aha, so you are only burning your wrapper token and the underlying token remains intact. Yup, that's easier since you do not need to rely on non-standard behavior from arbitrarily many other contracts.

Comment: Nope, in this case is the previously minted NFT that is burn. What I want to do is some Burner contract with a time-counter (so the original nft can have a last time to live and be sold in that time). If that doesn't happen the original nft is burned, if the sale happens it just goes to the buyer with the money for the original owner and a fee for my app. Is this possible in a way that the owner can be sure of the deal and only gives the permission once, when she gives her nft to the service?